# Custom form in Active Admin

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I am creating a custom form in Active Admin 0.5. I have registered a page and created a form through the DSL:

```
ActiveAdmin.register_page 'Planning', :namespace => :pos_admin do

  content :title => proc{ I18n.t("active_admin.dashboard") } do

    form do |f|
      f.input :type => :text
      f.input :type => :submit
    end

  end
end
```

The problem is that when submitting the form I get an empty Params hash. And the form tag contains no authenticity token.

What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 8):

An old post, but for anyone stumbling upon this issue, the answer is to add

```
f.input :name => 'authenticity_token', :type => :hidden, :value => form_authenticity_token.to_s
```

to the form. This passes the auth token back to ActiveAdmin so that it can confirm no forgery has taken place. Your session was being terminated and you were taken back to the login screen because ActiveAdmin thought you were trying to forge a submission.

Your form should now look like this

```
form do |f|
  f.input :name => 'authenticity_token', :type => :hidden, :value => form_authenticity_token.to_s
  f.input :type => :text
  f.input :type => :submit
end
```

Answer (score 0):

I use next syntax with AA forms (with   f.inputs do block)
Also you have to use property names of object for inputs

```
 form do |f|
   f.inputs do
     f.input :property_name,  :type => :text
   end
   f.actions
  end
```

Hope it will help!